# Efficient SAX Handling

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-parsing, sax

I have a series of XMLs containing postcodes with their corresponding latitude and longitude, like so;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<postcodes>
    <entry postcode='AB1 0AA' latitude='7.101478' longitude='2.242852' />
    <entry postcode='AB1 0AB' latitude='7.201458' longitude='2.122952' />
</postcodes>
```

The XMLs are split into post codes beginning with a certain letter, so there is one XML for each letter in the alphabet. Between them, they have every post code in the UK, which means the largest of these XML files has 300,000 `entry` elements.

I am looping through a list of Entity objects to put their post codes through SAX, to retrieve the `longitude` and `latitude` values against each post code. So, if I have 2000 entity objects, I am getting the SAX Handler to run 2000 times to retrieve those values. Code for the loop below;

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();

    for (Integer id : siteID){ 
            site = em.find(SiteTable.class, id);
            if(site != null && site.getPostcode() != null && !site.getPostcode().equals("")){
                XMLPositionRetriever.runXMLQuery(site.getPostcode()); 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The site and/or postcode against this Instruction does not exist.");
            }
     }
em.close();
```

`site.getPostcode()` becomes `postcodeToFind` in the Handler. Code for the only SAX Handler method being used below;

```
@Override 
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (postcodeToFind.equals(attributes.getValue("postcode"))){
        System.out.println("The postcode '"+postcodeToFind+"', has a latitude of "+attributes.getValue("latitude")+" and a longitude of "+attributes.getValue("longitude"));
        throw new SAXException();   
    }      
}
```

Currently this is time consuming (it takes just under 4 minutes for 2000 searches), but I need the load times to be fast. Under 30 seconds preferably. So far, I have managed to cut the load times down well below half by;

- Cutting down the number of times the Handler has to run, to only the essential number of times (by reducing the number of entities needing to be checked).
- Making the startElement() method throw an exception once the data I need has been found so that it doesn't continue to search unnecessarily.
- Breaking the XML files into smaller files (one for each letter of the alphabet), so that the handler has fewer elements to check per file.

**Q: Does anyone have any other suggestions for more efficient SAX handling?**

Comment: If memory is not a key requirement here, a dom tree of that file (maybe using modern techniques like JAXB or XStream) could speed this up by reading the file once and then accessing all stuff in memory. This can improve the performance by a substantial factor (at the cost of higher memory consumption)

Comment: You can use Apache Tika and use regular Expression to get that values

Comment: Use a database instead of XML files?

Comment: I suppose I could use an embedded DB, but the current SQL database I am pulling the Entity instances off is not mine to be messing with. As for DOM, this software will eventually have to run off of standard desktops with only 2gb of RAM, so storing 2.6 million elements in memory is probably something to be avoided.

Comment: Well it does not take so much memory as you have ~20byte per entry pure information. Parse the stuff once with your sax parser and store the result in a Map<String, Location>. If you sort your entities by post code, you could even recreate the map for every first letter of your postal codes to cut back on memory consumption.

Comment: On another idea, if you can presort the entities you want to find the postal codes for and your xml data is sorted, you can extract all relevant geo locations in one go of your sax parser. This should also be magnitudes faster then reparsing the whole structure for every entity.

Comment: @Matthias - Finding all locations in one go sounds fantastic. Would cut it down from 4 minutes to a few seconds or so. Pre-sorting the entities should be an easy one line job, but I can't see how I would retrieve the information in one pass of the handler. If you could write that up into an answer I would be happy to accept it (if I can get it to work).

Comment: @RudiKershaw posted an answer which shows how this could probably be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can pass all postal codes for which you want to retrieve the geo location to your handler, the handler could retrieve them in one go.
A SAXHandler doing this could look like this here:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXDemo extends DefaultHandler {

  private Map<String, Location> postalCodeMap;

  static class Location {
    String latitude;

    String longitude;
  }

  public SAXDemo(List<String> postalCodes) {
    this.postalCodeMap = new HashMap<String, SAXDemo.Location>();
    for (String postalCodeToLookFor : postalCodes) {
      this.postalCodeMap.put(postalCodeToLookFor, new Location());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    String postCodeOfElem = attributes.getValue("postcode");
    if (postCodeOfElem != null && this.postalCodeMap.containsKey(postCodeOfElem)) {
      Location loc = this.postalCodeMap.get(postCodeOfElem);
      loc.latitude = attributes.getValue("latitude");
      loc.longitude = attributes.getValue("longitude");
    }
  }

  public Location getLocationForPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    return this.postalCodeMap.get(postalCode);
  }

  public Map<String, Location> getAllFoundGeoLocations() {
    return this.postalCodeMap;
  }
}
```

Here you pass a List of Strings to the constructor of the handler and then let the handler parse the document with all your XML data.
After the parsing is completed, all retrieved geo locations can be found in the `postalCodeMap`

Comment: That is bloody genius. I'm going to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: It took quite a lot of messing my with my project to get this to work, and I had to compile all the postcodes XMLs into one large file with 2 and a half million elements. It took 1 full minute to just run the whole project before, most of which was being taken up by the SAX parsing. Now, the whole project runs in 10 seconds.

Comment: Hey, glad to hear it helped!